# Execute unexported function from library within c++ program

Tags: c++

I want to execute unexported function from library called `GetPhase` in my own library, which is java native agent.

As far as i know to call it, i must know exact function adress. I tried to get it using Ghidra and it's what i get:
[image]

I'm not sure if it's even correct function unfortunately, i wrote that code in c++ to get function in my code:

```
HMODULE hMod = GetModuleHandle("jvm.dll");
cout << "hMod: " << hMod << endl;

jvmtiPhase* phase_ptr = nullptr;
func* f = (func*) (DWORD_PTR) hMod + 0x086059b8;
f(phase_ptr);
```

But when i'm trying to attach my agent, i'm getting that exception:
[image]

What i'm doing wrong?

Source code of jvm.dll with function i want to get working in my code: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/94811c0dc7c20b0e7cb2649fe8da5061ce3d6246/src/hotspot/share/prims/jvmtiEnv.cpp#L764

PS I don't want to use it using JNI/JVMTI, i just want to execute that function directly

Comment: `GetPhase()` appears to be a class method. If it is a *non-static* class method (I can't find the declaration for it in that repo), then even if you had its address, you still wouldn't be able to call it like a standalone function, you would need an object instance of `JvmtiEnv` to call it on, which could explain why you are getting an access violation. Well, that, and you are passing a `nullptr` into it, which is not what it wants. It wants a pointer to a valid `jvmtiPhase` object, which the function then populates, eg `jvmtiPhase phase; f(&phase);`

Comment: According to Oracle docs, you can call it as it is exported via an interface. `jvmtiError GetPhase(jvmtiEnv* env, jvmtiPhase* phase_ptr)` `typedef enum {
 JVMTI_PHASE_ONLOAD = 1, JVMTI_PHASE_PRIMORDIAL = 2, JVMTI_PHASE_START = 6, JVMTI_PHASE_LIVE = 4, JVMTI_PHASE_DEAD = 8 } jvmtiPhase;` Ordinal #133 in the function table layout. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#GetPhase Unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: Just double checked: https://i.imgur.com/zZJnTJo.png it is exported officially and in the `jvmti.h` header (in Java JDK 8).

Comment: @Brandon but it require env pointer so how i would call it?

Comment: @Kaspek add: `JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Agent_OnLoad(JavaVM * jvm, char *options, void *reserved)` and then do: `(*jvm)->GetEnv(jvm, (void **) &jvmtiEnv,
      JVMTI_VERSION_1_0)`. So now you have a pointer to the `JVMTIEnv` and can call the function.